# How to call .html() within .html()?

Tags: jquery

I need to create something like this.
when I click on an image, it will fire the script below.

```
$("#txtHint").html("<form action='inline_spec.php' id = 'upLoadForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><center><input type='text' id='file' name = 'file' style='visibility:show' ></center></form>");
```

the script will open an text file input form. Upon submit the form, I need to display the result in txtHint.
Is it possible?

Comment: So what's the problem? Aside from using the deprecated `<center>` tag?

Comment: Submitting a form means the browser navigates to another page, so how could the hint be shown?

Comment: the form will appear within 'txtHint'. I wanted the result of the upLoadForm appear within 'txtHint' after I submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to put the result of the `upLoadForm` into `#textHint` unless you submit the form with AJAX. See the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for how to do that. Add the jQuery Form Plugin to the page and then replace your line of JS with this.

```
var $hint = $("#txtHint");
var $form = $("<form action='inline_spec.php' id = 'upLoadForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>")
                .appendTo($hint)
                .html("<center><input type='text' id='file' name = 'file' style='visibility:show' ></center>")
                .ajaxForm(function(response)
                {
                    $hint.html('Response from form post:<br/>' + response)
                });
```